# Failed to install QtCore4 on Ubuntu 16.10, perl version 5.24.1

Tags: c++, qt, perl

I am trying to install [`QtCore4`](https://metacpan.org/pod/QtCore4) on Ubuntu 16.10, perl version 5.24.1:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo apt-get install qt4-designer libqtgui4-perl
cpan -g QtCore4
bunzip2 Qt4-0.99.0.tar.bz2
tar xvf Qt4-0.99.0.tar
cd Qt4-0.99.0
perl Makefile.PL
make VERBOSE=1
```

Here `make` fails with error message:

```
Building CXX object smokeqt/qtdbus/CMakeFiles/smokeqtdbus.dir/x_1.cpp.o

cd /home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtdbus
/usr/bin/c++   -DSMOKE_BUILDING -Dsmokeqtdbus_EXPORTS \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtDesigner \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtScriptTools \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtDBus \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtXml \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtSql \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtXmlPatterns \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtHelp \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtUiTools \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtTest \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtScript \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtSvg \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui \
 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore \
 -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/default \
 -I/usr/include/qt4 \
 -I/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/src \
 -I/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt \
 -I/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokegen \
 -I/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtdbus \
 -I/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smoke \
 -I/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smoke/qtdbus  \
 -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC   -o CMakeFiles/smokeqtdbus.dir/x_1.cpp.o \
 -c /home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtdbus/x_1.cpp

/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtdbus/x_1.cpp:1594:7: error: deleted function ‘virtual __smokeqtdbus::x_QDBusConnectionInterface::~x_QDBusConnectionInterface()’
 class x_QDBusConnectionInterface : public QDBusConnectionInterface {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtDBus/QtDBus:8:0,
                 from /home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtdbus/qtdbus_includes.h:2,
                 from /home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtdbus/x_1.cpp:2:
/usr/include/qt4/QtDBus/qdbusconnectioninterface.h:73:5: error: overriding non-deleted function ‘virtual QDBusConnectionInterface::~QDBusConnectionInterface()’
     ~QDBusConnectionInterface();
     ^
/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtdbus/x_1.cpp:1594:7: note: ‘virtual __smokeqtdbus::x_QDBusConnectionInterface::~x_QDBusConnectionInterface()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class x_QDBusConnectionInterface : public QDBusConnectionInterface {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtdbus/x_1.cpp:1594:7: error: ‘virtual QDBusConnectionInterface::~QDBusConnectionInterface()’ is private within this context
```

These threads might be related:

- [What is this error message about implicitly deleted virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7587154/2173773)
- [PythonQt Dynamic Python binding for Qt Applications: build error in C++11 mode](https://sourceforge.net/p/pythonqt/discussion/631393/thread/568fa0c0/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there was a missing a destructor in the derived class `x_QDBusConnectionInterface`:

> /home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtdbus/x_1.cpp:1594:7: note: ‘virtual
>   __smokeqtdbus::x_QDBusConnectionInterface::~x_QDBusConnectionInterface()’
>   is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be
>   ill-formed:

By inserting a default destructor at line 1595 in `/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtdbus/x_1.cpp`:

```
~x_QDBusConnectionInterface();
```

the error disappeared. However, three other files now also had this missing destructor error:

- `/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtgui/x_3.cpp:4024`
- `/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtgui/x_13.cpp:3572`
- `/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qthelp/x_1.cpp:873`

Fixing these error the same way as the first, still a new error showed up:

```
/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/qtcore/src/util.cpp: In function ‘void
XS_AUTOLOAD(CV*)’: /home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/qtcore/src/util.cpp:2234:59:
error: cannot convert ‘bool’ to ‘void*’ in initialization    
     static smokeperl_object nothis = { 0, 0, 0, false };
                                                       ^
```

The definition of `smokeperl_object` is given in `/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/qtcore/src/smokeperl.h` at line 9:

```
struct smokeperl_object {
    bool allocated;
    Smoke* smoke;
    int classId;
    void* ptr;
};
```

According to this definition, replacing the `false` at `/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/qtcore/src/util.cpp:2234` with a `0` seemed to be a good try:

```
static smokeperl_object nothis = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

No recompiling fixed this error, but revealed yet a linker error:

```
/usr/bin/c++  -fPIC -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong \
 -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3 -DNDEBUG  \
 -shared -Wl,-soname,QtCore4.so -o ../../blib/arch/auto/QtCore4/QtCore4.so \
 CMakeFiles/perlqtcore4.dir/binding.cpp.o \
 CMakeFiles/perlqtcore4.dir/handlers.cpp.o \
 CMakeFiles/perlqtcore4.dir/marshall_types.cpp.o \
 CMakeFiles/perlqtcore4.dir/util.cpp.o \
 CMakeFiles/perlqtcore4.dir/QtCore4.c.o \
 -lQtCore -lQtGui -lQtNetwork \
 /home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/5.24.1/x86_64-linux/CORE/libperl.a \
 ../../smokeqt/qtgui/libsmokeqtgui.so.3.0.0 \
 ../../smokeqt/qtnetwork/libsmokeqtnetwork.so.3.0.0 \
 -lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc -lQtGui -lQtNetwork \
 ../../smokeqt/qtcore/libsmokeqtcore.so.3.0.0 -lQtCore \
 ../../smokegen/bin/libsmokebase.so.3.0.0 \
 -Wl,-rpath,/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtgui:/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtnetwork:/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokeqt/qtcore:/home/hakon/Qt4-0.99.0/smokegen/bin: 

/usr/bin/ld: /home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/5.24.1/x86_64-linux/CORE/libperl.a(toke.o): 
  relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `PL_curcop' can not be used when making
  a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am still not sure how to fix this last error..

Comment: Does recompiling with `-fPIC` (like the compiler suggests) help with the new issue?

Comment: @hlt I think it requires recompilation of the object files in `libperl.a` with `-fPIC` flag.. I am not sure how to do this, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43203477/2173773) question.

Comment: Added [cpan bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=121203)